# Excel Formula on the Formated output from a Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have case where i need to run the formula on the Date format which I cannot find in the search hit.
Here is my Need. In excell convert the Year & CalenderWeek to this format YYYY/MM/DD.

Some tried somehow with my nooby knowledge, but half:
[image]

Cell B4 has the formula (This converts value from B1 & B2 to date value. I have to select the date format to represent in the readable way)

```
=MAX(DATE(B1;1;1);DATE(B1;1;1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B1;1;1);2)+(B2-1)*7+1)
```

I Tried to split the result from B4 as in the Cell C4 with the below formula but it cannot act on that

```
=(LEFT(B4; SEARCH(".";B4;1)-1))
```

I coppied the textout put to notepad and then to Cell B6, from where i could split the date and rearrange in to output in the E7.

Could anyone please help me a way where the the Formula on C6 (or C4) directly run on the B4 Cell ?

Comment: Just rightclick on B4 -> Format cells -> in Number tab choose General -> Choose custom and type in: yyyy/mm/dd

Answer (score 1):

If `B4` contains an actual date, then try:

```
C4: =TEXTSPLIT(TEXT(B4,"mm.dd.yyy"),".")
```

and the results should `SPILL` as you show.

[image]